# how do you prune a cygwin download repository?

Tags: cygwin

I'm setting up a Cygwin server on a network behind a firewall. A clone of the cygwin.com download repository is 30G of noarch and 41G of x86_64 installers. However, many of the downloads seem to be redundant. For example, the zsh installer includes both 5.1.1 and 5.3.1. It also allows me to download both the source and the binaries:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xf86 pg101     310 Apr 29 06:44 md5.sum
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xf86 pg101     496 Apr 29 06:19 setup.hint
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xf86 pg101     883 Apr 29 06:44 sha512.sum
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xf86 pg101 6645833 Nov  1  2015 zsh-5.1.1-1-src.tar.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xf86 pg101 2360889 Nov  1  2015 zsh-5.1.1-1.tar.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xf86 pg101 6907837 Dec 19  2016 zsh-5.3-1-src.tar.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xf86 pg101 2454478 Dec 19  2016 zsh-5.3-1.tar.bz2
```

So this doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Is there an easy way to delete the obsolete packages? Can I just delete all of the source, or might I need it?

Comment: you need them only if you are planning to rebuild from source.

Comment: @matzeri, I can delete all  of the 'src' distributions, but why do I have both `zsh-5.1.1-1.tar.gz2` and `zsh-5 .3-1.tar.gz2`

Comment: current and previous version.